# How to loop through JSON object and view it as string - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I just started coding in swift and I am at the point that I can get a single value out of the JSON but I can't seem to get all the values out of it by looping trough the array. 
so my question is how do I get all the values out and view it as float or string.

here is my code:

```
 let url = URL(string: "http://api.fixer.io/latest")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    //print(myJson)

                    for items in myJson [AnyObject] {
                        print(items)
                    }

                    //here is the single value part, it looks for the rates then it puts it in label.

                    if let  rates = myJson["rates"] as? NSDictionary{


                        if let currency = rates["AUD"]{


                        print(currency);

                       self.label.text=String(describing: currency)


                        }





                    }

                }

                catch
                {


                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: This line doesn't make sense to me: `for items in myJson [AnyObject]` I would not expect that to compile. @aircraft's answer casts the JSON result to the correct type in the line that defines the myJSON constant. Aside from using an `as!` force cast, that is the better way to go. (I'd rewrite that as a guard statement that exits if the cast fails, since the format of data from a remote serve may change on you.)

Comment: As always, `mutableContainers` is completely meaningless in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#loop) to deal with JSON. It's extremely easy to learn and use.

first, you should install `SwiftyJSON` via CocoaPods (or any other way you like). then you can code it simply like below:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://api.fixer.io/latest")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {

                // Initialization
                let myJson = JSON(data: content)

                // Getting a string using a path to the element
                self.label.text = myJson["rates"]["AUD"].stringValue

                // Loop test
                for (key,value):(String, JSON) in myJson["rates"] {
                    print("key is :\(key), Value:\(value.floatValue)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: so now I made it work! but now it wont  show the whole list in an label it will only show last record. when I print it shows everything, any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.getJson()
}

func getJson(){

    let url = URL(string: "http://api.fixer.io/latest")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                        //Dic
                        guard let myJson:[String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] else {return}
                        //print(myJson)

                        for items in myJson {
                            print(items)
                        }

                        //here is the single value part, it looks for the rates then it puts it in label.

                        if let  rates = myJson["rates"] as? NSDictionary{


                            if let currency = rates["AUD"]{


                                print(currency);

                               // self.label.text=String(describing: currency)


                            }


                        }

                    }

                    catch
                    {


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

And the result in the console is like below:
[image]

The `myJson` is the dictionary what you want.

Comment: Good answer, except this line should be a guard statement:                         `guard let myJson:[String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] else {return}`

Comment: Your code uses a force cast, which is not safe for data from a remote server since you can't guarantee the format of data from a remote site.

Comment: @Duncan C, thanks your suggestion, your suggestion is considerate, great.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
    if let currency = rates["AUD"] as? NSDictionary{
         for(key,value) in currency {
            // the key will be your currency format and value would be your currency value
         }
    }
```